# Custom Animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

I am trying to achieve animation like below:

[image]

I tried with the PageRouteBuilder but could not achieve it. I had tried as follows:

```
class CustomPageRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget child;

  CustomPageRoute({
    required this.child,
  }) : super(
    transitionDuration:const Duration(milliseconds: 1400),
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => child,
        );

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) =>
      ScaleTransition(
          scale: animation,
          child: child);

}
```